# Footer doesn't look like I want. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problems with footer in on website. It's a bit strange because I have never had problems with footers.

I want to place the footer exactly like the menu, I'm using Bootstrap so I'm using columns but it's not working. I don't know why the space between elements on footer is different (all elements has the same number of columns) and also it doesn't start where the menu starts.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container"> <!--el container creo que hacía que los círculos se viesen más peques-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menupropio">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_menu img-responsive" src="images/logo_peque.png" alt="logo home"/></a>


      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="secciones">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border-bottom:0px">
          <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->

          <li><a href="kontakt.html" class="head-nav-button nav_graphicdesign">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Valik üle 20 aasta jooksul tehtud töödest</a></li> <!--todo los trabajos juntos -->
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Logod</a></li> <!--en esta pagina van todos los logos-->
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Trükised ja muu</a></li> <!--todo lo que no sean logos-->

        </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>




    <!--work designs starts-->
    <section class="row center-block text-center">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="res_publica.html"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="images/res_publica_valimiskampaania_kujundus_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Res Publica valimiskampaania"/>
          <span>Res Publica valimiskampaania</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="ajakiri_lofo.html"><img src="images/lofo_loodusfotoajakiri.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Ajakiri LoFo"/>
          <span>Ajakiri LoFo</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="kataloogid.html"><img src="images/kataloogid.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Kataloogid"/>
          <span>Kataloogid</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="hansab_logo.html"><img src="images/hansab_logo.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Hansab logo"/>
          <span>Hansab logo</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="hotelli_sildid.html"><img src="images/hotelli_do_not disturb_silt.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Hotelli sildid"/>
          <span>Hotelli sildid</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="mappkaaned.html"><img src="images/mappkaaned.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Mappkaaned"/>
          <span>Mappkaaned</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="seinakalender.html"><img src="images/seinakalender.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Seinakalender"/>
          <span>Seinakalender</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="rings">
          <a href="ajakiri_psyk.fi.html"><img src="images/ajakiri_psyk_fi.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Ajakiri Psyk.fi"/>
          <span>Ajakiri Psyk.fi</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

       </section>

  </div> <!--container-->


<footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-5 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <p>Kiige RB OÜ</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <a target="_blank" href="mailto:kiige@kiige.ee"><p>kiige@kiige.ee</p></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <p>+(372) 50 20 506</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <p>Tuleme hea meelega teile külla!</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

and CSS:

```
footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

If you want to take a look at the website, this is the provisional link: http://clients.sabrinacouto.com/kiige/

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All your sections seem to use "row"

```
<section class="row center-block text-centre">
```

However, your footer doesn't have a row surrounding your columns to negate the spacing it adds. Col always adds an additional spacing to both sides. The row is there to negate that spacing if you have multiple cols.

Comment: Ok, now I added row and footer starts where menu starts. But I still have the problem with the space between elements (for example, the space between "Kiige RB OÜ" and email is bigger than the space between "+(372) 50 20 506" and "Tuleme hea meelega teile külla!". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit in your html as like this may it helps you

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <p>Kiige RB OÜ</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a target="_blank" href="mailto:kiige@kiige.ee"><p>kiige@kiige.ee</p></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <p>+(372) 50 20 506</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <p>Tuleme hea meelega teile külla!</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Well, it looks better than my option. But it's still not the same as menu. I suppose that it's not possible due to the size of the columns? and also the last phrase is too long. Thanks!